# Is there a way to include null values along with selected values in query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When filtering multiple categories, I am attempting to add a new filter to a current concatenated string that updates what has been selected, but also includes null values to an sql statement. I have tried (query += query & color = selected OR query & color Is Null, but it ends up only grabbing the non null values.

Here is an example of something I've tried

```
If Nz(colorFilter, "-") <> "All" Then
    query = query & " AND Color Is Null OR Color=" & Chr(34) & Me.colorFilter & Chr(34) & query
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = query & " AND (Color Is Null OR Color = " & Chr(34) & Me.colorFilter & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Need that closing paren concatenated inside quote marks? Maybe add explanation for use of parentheses.

Comment: Yes, with that closing quote marks added, this was exactly what worked. Thank you so much @Gustav